# Tag search while retrieving tag-siblings

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

If I need to fetch rows from table A with a matching tag in table B, I'll just do a simple JOIN ON/WHERE B.name=X. But MySQL will then only return the row from A and the matching tag from B.

What do I do if I want to retrieve all from table A that has a match in table B, and *at the same time* retrieve all from table B that are linked to the row in table A.

```
A:
a.id
1
2
3

B: 
b.id   | b.a_id   | b.name
1      | 1        | foo
2      | 1        | bar
3      | 1        | derp
4      | 2        | foo
5      | 2        | derp
6      | 3        | bar

A search for "foo" should then return
a.id   | b.id     | b.a_id   | b.name
1      | 1        | 1        | foo
1      | 2        | 1        | bar
1      | 3        | 1        | derp
2      | 4        | 2        | foo
2      | 5        | 2        | derp
```

Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, b.name FROM a 
RIGHT JOIN b ON (a.id = b.a_id) 
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.a_id FROM b WHERE b.name = 'foo')
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Might not be the most performant solution, but I hope it will work.

Edit:

```
SELECT a_new.id, b.id, b.name FROM 
    (SELECT b.a_id FROM b WHERE b.name = 'foo') AS a_new
RIGHT JOIN b ON (a_new.id = b.a_id)
```

I don't think it'll get any better than this, basically you don't need to query the table a anymore; you fetch all rows from b that match 'foo', then join those with all relating items.

Comment: Ye, that works. Does there exist a more performant solution, however?

Comment: Documentation states that EXISTS is extremely slow because the inner statement is rerun for each row. I do not know if IN uses the same behaviour, though. Let me see, I think something like this might work:

SELECT a_new.id, b.id, b.name FROM (SELECT b.a_id FROM b WHERE b.name = 'foo') AS a_new RIGHT JOIN b ON (a_new.id = b.a_id)

Comment: I might be thinking too much about Oracle, but I believe the opposite is true for any SQL database. I explained more in my answer.

Comment: Ill accept this answer since it was first and has the suggestion for "EXISTS" in the comment. I appreciate the help from both of you. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. His final solution is definitely better though. I would use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM a JOIN b on b.a_id = a.id 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from b where a_id = a.id and b.name = 'foo')
```

After the comment storm, I realized what you were trying to ask. This should be a faster solution than IN clauses.

There are some nasty problems with IN clauses, namely that the cursor has to be reopned for every row returned, as MySQL has to examine each value in it. The EXIST clause can reuse the cursor since it's just checking that it exists at all. Remember, the number of distinct queries that actually need to be run in this case is equal to the number of values in a. Since the cursors are just opened to test for existence and not read, there's no need to create a new one unless the query is different.

I'd have to track down some documentation to back this up for MySQL, but this is the case in Oracle.

Comment: It will, but it doesnt let me filter by a specific b.name value. And if I add an b.name="foo", then only the row where b.name="foo" will be returned from B.

Comment: Well, what exactly were you hoping it would return? I'm not sure what you're going for here...

Comment: Look at the third table in the OP :)

Comment: Yeah, I see what you wrote, but I'm not clear on what you're wanting out of this. If you want to show everything in that table, the query I provided will do so. You can't filter out some values *and* show all values at the same time. What are you trying to do, exactly? It sounds like you're asking for two contradictory things to happen.

Comment: Your solution will also return rows from A that arent tied to a b.name="foo" row.

Comment: I think @manuFS answered this. However, you might need to refine your example to add another row to a that *doesn't* have a corresponding "foo" value in b. Based on your example, my query will return what you see in the third table. Would definitely have made this more clear.

Comment: i see I forgot a row in the first table. My bad.